# Getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I don't know why i'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` while setting adaptor to the `autocomplete`. Exactly this statement generates this exception:

```
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have both the layout's in the layout folder.

```
         AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     helpBuilder.setTitle("Search Location");
     LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
     View PopupLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_autocomplete, null);
     helpBuilder.setView(PopupLayout);
     AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
     helpDialog.show();
     textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.locationAutoCompleteTv);
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list);
     adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
     textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Well, either `textView` is `null` or `adapter` is `null`. Just `System.out.println` them to find out. -1 because this would be very easy to debug on your own.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Yup i was getting null on textview, which i had solved by helpDialog.findViewById.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that line is throwing a `NullPointerException`, it must be that `textView` is null.

This is probably because your `findViewById` call gave an id which was not found in the view.

You haven't given us enough information to be sure, but I suspect you're trying to grab a textView in the helpDialog you just showed. Try replacing `findViewById` with `helpDialog.findViewById`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my problem by using instance of helpDialog.findViewById. 
And sorry It was really a dumb question. I had to figured out my own.